# Finite field has $t^p - 1 = (t-1)^p$.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Consider the field $\mathbb{Z} / p \mathbb{Z}$, where $p$ is a prime number.

I'm reading Lang's *Undergraduate Algebra*, and he asserts that $t^p - 1 = (t-1)^p$. Why is this true?

Thanks!

Comment: Binomial theorem + definition of prime number.

Comment: Gotcha, thanks. I needed Timbuc's answer before I successfully parsed this hint.

Comment: Look up "freshman's dream."

Comment: That's pretty cute.

Comment: The result is even stronger, as you may have seen in the Wikipedia article for freshman's dream: $(x+y)^p = x^p + y^p$ in all finite fields of characteristic $p$.

Comment: @kaj that's true in all fields of characteristic $\;p\;$, finite or not.

Comment: @Timbuc, doh!  You are right.  That's what I intended to put; I don't know how "finite" slipped in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\forall\; 1\le k\le p-1\;,\;\;p\mid\binom pk$$